# Prove or disprove the inequality $ -x\ln (x)\leq \ln(1-x)(\ln (x) + 1 - x)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

how can one disprove or prove the equation below? I have already reduced it to its simplest form (according to me) and I am kind of stuck at this point:

$$ -x\ln (x)\leq \ln(1-x)(\ln (x) + 1 - x) \qquad\text{for}\qquad 0\lt x\lt 1$$

Any help will be quite useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: prove/disprove, not "approve/disapprove"

Comment: Do you mean $$-x\ln(x)\le \ln(1-x)(\ln(x)+1-x)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes I mean that

Comment: I think you mean $\ge$, not $\le$. The inequality you wrote down is not true for $0 < x < 1$, but if you switch it to $\ge$ instead of $\le$ then it is true.

Comment: This inequalitiy is not true, take $$x=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @6005
how do you know that it is not true, which steps did you take to solve it

Comment: I plugged in $$x=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @Dr okay, how about a mathematical proof like step wise and if I change the sign then it is true, how can I prove that then

Comment: @dr.SonnhardGraubner can the equation be reduced further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality
 $$ -x\ln x\leq \ln(1-x)(\ln x + 1 - x) \qquad\text{for}\qquad 0\lt x\lt 1$$

is not true.
For example, if we put in $x = \frac{1}{2}$ we get
$$
- \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1}{2} = \frac12  \ln 2 = 0.34\ldots
$$
and
$$
\ln\left(1 - \frac12\right) 
\left( \ln \frac12 + 1 - \frac12\right)
= \left(- \ln 2 \right) \left( \frac12 - \ln 2 \right) = (\ln 2)^2 - \frac12 \ln 2 = 0.13 \ldots
$$

and $0.34 \ldots > 0.13\ldots$.

---

You probably made a mistake when you reduced it to this form. If you reverse the inequality, it would be true. 
See the graph below:

[image]

We can see that the graph looks to be $> 0$ for $0 < x < 1$.
So we conjecture that the inequality
$$
- x \ln x \ge \ln(1-x) (\ln x + 1 - x)
$$
will be true.

Comment: Thank you, just one more question, can we reduce the equation further(make it more simpler) so that it is intuitively possible as to why it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have $$-\ln(1-x)(\ln(x)+1-x)-x\ln(x)\geq 0$$ for $$0<x<1$$

Answer (score 0):

Define
\begin{align*}
f(x) = -x\log(x) - \log(1-x)(\log(x) + 1 - x)
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. Note that
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= f(1) = 0 \\
f'(x) &= \frac{(x-1)\log(1-x)}{x} + \frac{x\log(x)}{1-x} \begin{cases}
> 0 & x < \frac{1}{2} \\
= 0 & x = \frac{1}{2} \\
< 0 & x > \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f(x) \ge \min(f(0), f(1)) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=x\ln (x)+ \ln(1-x)\,(\ln (x) + 1 - x) $$ and notice the symmetry which makes that
$$f(x)+f(1-x)=0$$ Compute $f(x)$ anywhere to show that is negative. Using $x=\frac 12$, you have $(\log (2)-1) \log (2)$ which is the minimum value.